# How to Mock a ResponseEntity<?> method

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am implementing unit tests in Spring Boot but I can't get them to work.

Here is my method n the RoulletController class.

```
@PutMapping("/open_roulette/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> enableRoluette(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        return rouletteService.enableRouletteById(id);
    }
```

Here is my method on the RouletteService class.

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> enableRouletteById(Long roulette_id) {
        Optional<Roulette> roulette = rouletteRepository.findById(roulette_id);
        HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (roulette.isPresent()) {
            Roulette request = roulette.get();
            {
                if (!request.isRouletteStatus())
                    request.setBets(null);
            }
            request.setRouletteStatus(true);
            rouletteRepository.save(request);
            response.put("message", "La ruleta ha sido activada con éxito");
            response.put("roulette", request);

            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } else {
            response.put("message", "La apuesta no es correcta");
            response.put("error", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

And here is my test method RoulletControllerTest class, i'm trying to do soemthing like this but i got "The method thenReturn is not applicable for the arguments, etc.

```
@Test
    public void testEnableRoluette() {

        HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);

        Mockito.when(rouletteService.enableRouletteById(14L)).thenReturn(responseEntity);
        assertEquals(rouletteController.enableRoluette(14L), responseEntity);
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the `?` parameter of the `ResponseEntity`. It works if you give the real type, ie. ResponseEntity>.

The error message hints at that. It is expecting `CAP#2` but is getting `CAP#1`:

```
ControllerTest.java:26: error: no suitable method found for thenReturn(ResponseEntity<CAP#1>)
            .thenReturn (responseEntity);
            ^
    method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(ResponseEntity<CAP#2>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ResponseEntity<CAP#1> cannot be converted to ResponseEntity<CAP#2>)
    method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(ResponseEntity<CAP#2>,ResponseEntity<CAP#2>...) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; ResponseEntity<CAP#1> cannot be converted to ResponseEntity<CAP#2>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

You can also improve your code by moving the response handling to the controller. Your service should just returns the `Map<>`. This removes the dependency on the web layer and the service is easier to reuse in other code.